# How do I add an arbitrary file to /public with Gatsby?

Tags: gatsby, netlify

I would like to add a text file to `/src` in a way that it always ends up unchanged in the root of the build directory (`/public`).

In my case specifically I need to add a `_redirects` [file](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/) for Netlify to redirect a subdomain to a custom domain.

Running Gatsby 1.0 alpha.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Didn't need to put it in `/src`. I just added it directly to `/public`.

Even though it's in `.gitignore`, I used `git add -f /public/_redirects`, committed it, and it worked. It doesn't get deleted or overwritten during build.

---

Another way to do this (which I haven't tested) is to is to copy the file to its destination in /public as part of a [post-build script](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/872#issuecomment-298046002) in gatsby-node.js.

Comment: Adding it to the post-build script worked. One note is to replace `postBuild` with `onPostBuild`.
E.g. as used here: https://spectrum.chat/gatsby-js/general/generating-json-file-with-gatsby~c539d9a7-970c-4a52-ac79-18a51f254537?m=MTUyMzk5NjM1OTk2Nw==

Comment: This isn't working, trying to send only `index.html` file with inline css style `user-select: none;` embedded, just ran the command `git add -f public/index.html`, pushed to Netlify, and the user can still select. Any hints would be great.

Answer (score 33):

A bit late to the party.

The easiest way is to add `static` folder in your project root directory, then place `_redirects` inside it. Then when you build Gatsby will automatically pick that up and place it within `/public` folder.

See [official docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-images-fonts-files/#using-the-code-classlanguage-textstaticcode-folder)

Answer (score 1):

Gatsby [now recommends using the `./static/` directory](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/images-and-media/static-folder/) for files to be copied verbatim into the build destination.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question answered, I found another way to do this and I wanted to share. Just copy your `_redirects` file or any file during build time, like this:

```sh
"build": "gatsby build && cp src/_redirects public/"
```

and it will copy your file everytime you build for deployment. I hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar issue by installing `gatsby-plugin-copy-files-enhanced` plugin and editing **gatsby-config.js** like the following:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `extra`,
    path: `${__dirname}/src/extra`,
  },
},
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-copy-files-enhanced',
  options: {
    source: `${__dirname}/src/extra`,
    destination: '/',
    purge: false,
  },
},
```

***Note:** Don't forget to move your `_redirects` file to `src/extra`.*